# Payum Bundle Symfony events

Tags: symfony, payum

I try add to config payum evens extension

```
payum.extension.event_dispatcher:
  class: Payum\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Extension\EventDispatcherExtension
  arguments: ["@event_dispatcher"]
  tags:
    - { name: payum.extension, all: true, prepend: false }
```

get error

```
Argument 1 passed to Payum\Core\Gateway::addExtension() must implement interface Payum\Core\Extension\ExtensionInterface, string given, called in /application/vendor/payum/core/Payum/Core/CoreGatewayFactory.php on line 249
```

I create if from this manual

https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/event-dispatcher.md